# How to fix stack smashing detected in C on a else if statement?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char response[5];
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("Are You Looking For Commonly Used Software?\n Enter Yes or No: ");
    scanf("%s", response);
    if (strcmp(response, "yes")==0){
        printf("What software are you looking For?: ");
        scanf("%s", response);
        if (strcmp(response, "gimp")==0){
            printf("sudo pacman -S gimp");
        }
        else if (strcmp(response, "blender")==0){
            printf("sudo pacman -S blender");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("See you later then!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my my Code For a school project I am working on I wrote it in python at first but as a Challenge I am trying to write it in C. The code compiles fine with gcc only giving out a warning for implicit declaration of function strcmp on line 9. When I run the code it works fine unless I enter blender. Then it outputs

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[1]    29996 abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: What's your input? Your `response` has space for strings of length 4 at most, yet you compare it to `"blender"`.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `scanf`, use `fgets`, or at least give it a length specifier.

Comment: Hint: How long is `"blender"` and what sized buffer would you need to hold it? Don't use these microscopic buffers of size `5`. Be generous, use `1024` as a default for "arbitrary input field".

Comment: Why haven't you fixed the implicit declaration? You need `#include <string.h>`

Comment: "Implicit declaration" is one of those warnings that you ought to treat like an error; don't bother to try and run your code until you've fixed it.  (That goes for most warnings, actually.)  Missing declarations can cause all sorts of subtle and time-wasting misbehavior.  Many people are disappointed that gcc doesn't make this warning an actual error, as the C standard would allow it to do.

Comment: You may as well get used to run GCC with the option `-Werror` (turn all warnings into errors).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the <string.h> library.